# XPages templates are not loaded

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse, ibm-oneui

i'm working on domino server v9.0.1 and from some days my web applications have a problem:
-standard templates aren't loaded!

My applications are based on oneuiv2.1.

What can be the problem? Applications was working fine some days ago... 
I think the only operations made on the server are about user maintenance, like deleting some administrator users but xpages applications are now signed by the server.

There are no errors on lotus domino console and on the opened xpages

Have you any idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are there any error messages on the server? There's not enough information to offer any specific solutions.

Comment: Sorry:There are no errors on lotus domino console and on the opened xpages.

i've edited my post

Comment: What do you mean by 'standard templates'? Reading your description I think that the stylesheets (.css files) aren't loaded anymore. Is that correct? If yes: please check with Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug if the links are still in there and try to open them directly. That might give you clue about what's going on.

Comment: What does "just the template (css and more) isn't loaded"? Do you get a 404 when loading CSS files in the browser?

Comment: "I think the only operations made...". So maybe you should contact your administrators to ask what they did on the server during the last days?

Comment: Thank you all for answers,

No errors appear on my console and no 404.
If i check with firebug my pages i didn't see the css inclusions.
It's seems templates aren't applied to my xpage application but if i check xsp properties i see template "oneuiv2.1" speciefied.

I cannot ask any system administrator if they have made changes on server because our admin is fired :S This is the reason why "i think the only operations made are user deletion on server"...

Comment: Is it the application that's not loading in a browser or the design not refreshing down to applications? If the former, you should get some error message on the browser. 403=signed by wrong ID, 404=NSF or design note not found, 500=XPages error which writes to server console and xpagesexc log files. Remember if you're trying to view the NTF in the web, you can't (not sure if that's a possibility from your question)

Comment: so, i have my application with "oneuiv2.1" specified in "application theme" properties field.
I have an xpage with "Application Layout" custom control but when i load my application in a browser i didn't see the application layout and themes css... and there are no errors on my server console!

Comment: Can you open *http://your.server/oneuiv2/base/core.css* ?

Comment: no! i've tried from my server and i get 404... i've tried with another server and it works fine..

Comment: ok... so my Lotus\Domino\Data\domino\html was deleted from someone... thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my Lotus\Domino\Data\domino\html was deleted... i've copied template folders from other server and now all it's working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Is the server allowed to run the xpages ?

Comment: Xpages applications are working... just the template (css and more) isn't loaded